# How do I remove filters if filter already exists and create new filter in Google Scripts

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, filter

I am trying to create a script that runs across 11 different sheets throughout my google sheet. This function essentially will just remove the current filter (if applicable) and create a filter with updated information. The problem I am running into is that my logic to only remove the filter if it does not equal null doesn't seem to be working because I keep getting an "Exception: you can't create a filter in a sheet that already has a filter" however my `filter.remove` should have already removed it.I have been staring at this for hours, some help would be really appreciated.  Here is a copy of my script, its a bit long, preferably I would also like to shorten it if possible.

```
function Filter_All() {
///Set Variables
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var filter = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter();
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  var daycount = 0
  var MILLIS_PER_DAY = 1000*60*60*24*daycount
  var now = new Date();
  var filterdate = new Date(now.getTime() - MILLIS_PER_DAY);
///Select "MTD Assignments"
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('MTD-Assignments'), true);
///Remove filter
    if (filter !== null) {
    filter.remove();
    }
///Create Filter
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange('A:N').createFilter();
  criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .whenDateAfter(filterdate)
  .build();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(5, criteria);
///Select "Torian"
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Torian'), false);
///Remove filter
    if (filter !== null) {
    filter.remove();
    return;
    }
///Create Filter
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange('A:N').createFilter();
  criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .whenDateAfter(filterdate)
  .build();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(5, criteria);
///Select "Luke"
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Luke'), false);
///Remove filter
    if (filter !== null) {
    filter.remove();
    return;
    }
///Create Filter
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange('A:N').createFilter();
  criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .whenDateAfter(filterdate)
  .build();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(5, criteria);
///Select "Charity"
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Charity'), false);
///Remove filter
    if (filter !== null) {
    filter.remove();
    return;
    }
///Create Filter
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange('A:N').createFilter();
  criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .whenDateAfter(filterdate)
  .build();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(5, criteria);
///Select "Tenisha"
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Tenisha'), false);
///Remove filter
    if (filter !== null) {
    filter.remove();
    return;
    }
///Create Filter
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange('A:N').createFilter();
  criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .whenDateAfter(filterdate)
  .build();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(5, criteria);
///Select "Shannon"
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Shannon'), false);
///Remove filter
    if (filter !== null) {
    filter.remove();
    return;
    }
///Create Filter
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange('A:N').createFilter();
  criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .whenDateAfter(filterdate)
  .build();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(5, criteria);
///Select "Siley"
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Siley'), false);
///Remove filter
    if (filter !== null) {
    filter.remove();
    return;
    }
///Create Filter
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange('A:N').createFilter();
  criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .whenDateAfter(filterdate)
  .build();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(5, criteria);
///Select "Macheera"
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Macheera'), false);
///Remove filter
    if (filter !== null) {
    filter.remove();
    return;
    }
///Create Filter
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange('A:N').createFilter();
  criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .whenDateAfter(filterdate)
  .build();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(5, criteria);
///Select "Nia"
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Nia'), false);
///Remove filter
    if (filter !== null) {
    filter.remove();
    return;
    }
///Create Filter
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange('A:N').createFilter();
  criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .whenDateAfter(filterdate)
  .build();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(5, criteria);
///Select "Alicia"
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Alicia'), false);
///Remove filter
    if (filter !== null) {
    filter.remove();
    return;
    }
///Create Filter
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange('A:N').createFilter();
  criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .whenDateAfter(filterdate)
  .build();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(5, criteria);
///Select "Shannon/Johan/Meybeling"
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Shannon/Johan/Meybeling'), false);
///Remove filter
    if (filter !== null) {
    filter.remove();
    return;
    }
///Create Filter
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange('A:N').createFilter();
  criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .whenDateAfter(filterdate)
  .build();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(5, criteria);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your error may be as follows:

On line 4, you assign the value of the variable `filter` as the filter for the sheet 'MTD-Assignments'.  In line 14, you remove that filter from the sheet.  On line 22, you set the active sheet as 'Torian', and then on line 24 you again call `filter.remove()`.  However, even though you've changed the active sheet, this does not change the `filter` variable to point at the filter for the new active sheet: `filter` still points at the filter for 'MTD-Assignments'.  So line 24 does not remove the filter from the sheet 'Torian'.  To do so, you first need to re-assign the value of `filter` by repeating the line

```
 filter = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter()
```

*after* you've set the active sheet to 'Torian' and before you call `filter.remove()` again.

Something like this:

```
///Set Variables
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var filter = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter();
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  var daycount = 0
  var MILLIS_PER_DAY = 1000*60*60*24*daycount
  var now = new Date();
  var filterdate = new Date(now.getTime() - MILLIS_PER_DAY);
///Select "MTD Assignments"
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('MTD-Assignments'), true);
///Remove filter
    if (filter !== null) {
    filter.remove();
    }
///Create Filter
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange('A:N').createFilter();
  criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .whenDateAfter(filterdate)
  .build();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(5, criteria);
///Select "Torian"
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Torian'), false);
filter = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter();  // This is the line to be added.
///Remove filter
    if (filter !== null) {
    filter.remove();
    return;
    }
///Create Filter
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange('A:N').createFilter();
  criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .whenDateAfter(filterdate)
  .build();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(5, criteria);
```

And similarly for your other sheets.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know that, it is very helpful. I am new to this type of thing so I appreciate any feedback that can be provided. This will surely be something I will keep in mind when creating future scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function Filter_All() {
  // set variables
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var daycount = 0
  var MILLIS_PER_DAY = 1000*60*60*24*daycount
  var now = new Date();
  var filterdate = new Date(now.getTime() - MILLIS_PER_DAY);
  var filterCriteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
    .whenDateAfter(filterdate)
    .build();

  // reset filter for each sheet in loop
  var sheetNamesWithFilter = ['MTD-Assignments', 'Torian']; // TODO fill with your sheet names
  for (var i = 0; i < sheetNamesWithFilter.length; i++)
  {
    var sheetName = sheetNamesWithFilter[i];

    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);

    // remove filter
    var filter = sheet.getFilter();
    if (filter !== null)
    {
      filter.remove();
    }

    // create filter
    sheet.getRange('A:N').createFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(5, filterCriteria);
  }
}
```

Basically all you need to get your script to work is use *loop* and apply same filter changes for each sheet in a loop. It is considered best practice with repeating same commands, and also can help you to get rid of unintentional errors like you had, when you mistakenly forgot to update `filter` variable for your next iteration.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I am new to this type of thing so forgive my inaccuracies, but I strive to learn more every day and your input was very helpful. It also helped to show some gaps in my knowledge. Thanks again for your help!